# How to use rustc crates in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, clion

I'm trying to use rustc crates (e.g. rustc_lint) in CLion with the Rust plugin, but to no avail. I got it working in VSCode rust-analyzer, but I prefer CLion. The issue with CLion is that it simply doesn't detect the crates. I get an error "Can't find crate for rustc_lint" (it's only in the IDE, `cargo check` finds no issues), thus, no documentation or autocomplete is available.

Comment: On my system, all these crates are stored at `/home/<user>/.rustup/toolchains/<toolchain>/lib/rustlib/rustc-src/rust/compiler/rustc_*`. I've never used CLion, but if you're able to add some sort of additional "search paths", you could try adding these paths.